# How to apply Dirichlet and Neumann boundary condition at the corner in Finite-Element-Method?

Tags: finite-element

I have a 2D rectangular domain. The governing equation on this domain is Laplace equation:

∇2f=0

In the left and right edge  there is Neumann boundary conditon : ∂f∂n=a

n is the normal vector to the domain's boundary(here on the left edge it's equal to the negative direction of x axis) and 'a' is a given date and it's a constant.

There is a Dirichlet boundary condition at the bottom and upper  edge.

My problem is how to apply that bc at the corner nodes since there are two different bcs located at the same node.

Comment: Neumann boundary conditions are not imposed at points in the FEM, but on faces. You don't have to deal with these corner vertices any differently than any other vertex that has a Dirichlet boundary condition imposed on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback . But I think we need to multiply test function Ni   with each node of the face, it still can be thought as imposed at the points

Comment: No, you should think of it as a boundary integral. You can of course approximate this boundary integral via quadrature, specifically using the trapezoidal rule that only evaluates at vertices, but it's still an integral you're computing.